# Лютівник чи паяльник?

Tags: вибір-слова, росіянізм, архаїзми

У [словниках](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on), укладених на початку ХХ століття, є такий відповідник російського паяльник:

> Російсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С.
>   Єфремов)
>
> **Пая́ло і Пая́льник** – лютува́ло, лютува́льник.
>   **Нажига́льник** – жига́ло (паяльник) лютува́ло, лютува́льник (-ка).
>   **Опа́йщик** (паяльник) – лютовни́к (-ка).
>
> Російсько-український словник 1930р. (О. Ізюмов)
>
> **Паяльник** – лютува́ло, -ла, лютува́льник, -ка.
>
> Російсько-український словник технічної термінології 1928р. (І. Шелудько, Т. Садовський)
>
> **Паяльник** (инструм.) – лют(ів)ни́к (-ка́);
>
> • п., паяльщик – люта́р (-ря́);
>
> • п. газовый – лютни́к газо́вий;
>
> • п. молоткообразный – л. молоткува́тий;
>
> • п. остроконечный – л. гостроно́сий;
>
> • п. электрический – л. електри́чний.
>
> **Опайщик**(паяльник.) – лютівни́к (-ка́).
>
> Російсько-український словник військової термінології 1928р. (С. та О. Якубські)
>
> **Паяльник** — лютівни́к, -ка́.

Але ані СУМ-11, ані СЛОВНИК УКРАЇНСЬКОЇ МОВИ ONLINE слів лутувальник, лютувало, лютар не містять. Натомісць з'явилося [паяльник](http://sum.in.ua/s/pajaljnyk), паяльщик, паяльщиця. Вікіпедія також містить сторінку зі статтею [Паяльник](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA).

Чи слово лютівник зникло зі вжитку, чи є застарілим, які були підстави для його заміни на паяльник?

Answer (score 3):

У тлумачному онлайн словнику української мови маємо слово "[лютар](http://www.classes.ru/all-ukrainian/dictionary-ukrainian-explanatory-term-80679.htm#)" у значенні "паяльник" і з позначкою "західноукраїнське", і там же є слово "[паяльник](http://www.classes.ru/all-ukrainian/dictionary-ukrainian-explanatory-term-114612.htm)", що означає "ручний інструмент для паяння". А згідно до [цього джерела](http://movahistory.org.ua/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B1%D1%8E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C._%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0) слово "лютник" - це полонізм (пол. "lutownica").

І як ви вже самі написали у СУМі немає такого слова як "лютар" чи "лютівник", а тому краще вживати слово "паяльник".

Comment: Додам, що [«Толковый словарь украинского языка» на classes.ru](http://www.classes.ru/all-ukrainian/dictionary-ukrainian-explanatory.htm) (на який Ви посилаєтеся) — це, найімовірніше, [«ВТССУМ»](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Великий_тлумачний_словник_сучасної_української_мови).

Comment: *Лютар* - явний германізм через польське посередництво, як і велика кількість інших західноукраїнських діалектних слів.

Answer (score 1):

Так, [словник чужомовних слів Павла Штепи 1977 року](//archive.org/stream/shtepa1977/shtepa1977_djvu.txt) теж радить:

> *паяльник (прилад) — лютничка;
>
>   паяльщик (людина) — лютнач;
>
>   паяти — лютувати, залютовувати, залютувати, позалютовувати, злютовувати, злютувати, налютовувати, полютовувати, полютувати, прилютовувати, прилютувати, поприлютовувати, улютовувати, улютувати, повлютовувати*

Цікаво, СУМ „людину“ не позначають, дієслова [*лютувати*](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=48825) — так, правда, з позначкою *рідко*. Також Грінченко справляє на користь *[лютувати](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/27224-ljutuvaty.html)*: *2) паять*, оскільки ніц на *пая∗* не знаходиться. Правда, *паяти* в старішому словнику — 1893–1898; М. Уманець, А. Спілка — [знаходиться](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C&highlight=on), однак всюди є згадка *лют∗*.

Так, *лютува́ти* взяте [через](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom3.pdf#page=331) польську від німецького [першоджерела](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8) є *löt* «свинець». Окрім польської, також цього мають, наприклад, [словацька](//sk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sp%C3%A1jkovanie). Однак, я був б обережним, оскільки, впродовж всього часу, українська має вдосталь [германських](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BC) слів, котрі вельми прижилися як рідні. Тому, гадаю, слово має право на вжив, хай як би [не казали](http://movahistory.org.ua/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B1%D1%8E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C._%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0) згадані [паном Анатолій](/a/4263) відверті просовітські мовці, котрі мали ціль не скільки чистомовства, а омосковчення, бо московська брала і досі має [полонізми](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BC#%D0%A3_%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96), [галліцизми](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC), германізми та тощо не згірш за українську. Схоже, це і була одна з підстав зникнення тямки.

Так, слово *паяти* [виглядає](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom4.pdf#page=325) ближчим через старословʼянське, або ж точніше [старо·церковнословʼянське](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2'%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0), *съпоити* «зʼєднати» і ширшу поширеність серед словʼянських мов. [Також](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?root=%2Fusr%2Flocal%2Fshare%2Fstarling%2Fmorpho&morpho=1&basename=morpho%5Cvasmer%5Cvasmer&first=1&off=&text_word=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C&method_word=substring&ic_word=on&text_general=&method_general=substring&ic_general=on&text_origin=&method_origin=substring&ic_origin=on&text_trubachev=&method_trubachev=substring&ic_trubachev=on&text_editorial=&method_editorial=substring&ic_editorial=on&text_pages=&method_pages=substring&ic_pages=on&text_any=&method_any=substring&sort=word&ic_any=on) є цікаві зауваження про [фіно-угорських мов](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8#%D0%92%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%83_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83) і думка Кипарського в 1956 році, що можлива спільність з «поїти, пити», тоді за тямкою споріднене з фінською *juottaa* та естонською *jооtа*, котрі означають «паяти» та «пити» водночас.

Comment: Здається в останньому абзаці ви навели цитату? Якщо там, то її треба оформити як цитату і вказати звідки.